# Twig error Item "detailIndex" for "Array" does not exist in

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm study symfony and want to display a variable in my twig template.
Here is my PHP code:

```
{% for row in issue.data %}
    {{ dump(row) }}
```

and that what i got on my site:

```
array(size=5)
  'positionId' =>int5
  'position' =>int5
  'cost' =>float3000
  'detailIndex' =>int1
  'hours' =>int3
```

so i'm using:

```
{{ row.detailIndex }}
```

to access my array variable, but got error:

```
Item "detailIndex" for "Array" does not exist in
```

That's very strange, because i easily can get access to this variables:

```
{{ row.hours }}
{{ row.position }}
{{ row.cost }}
```

I'll apreciate any help from your, my friends!

Comment: This is strange, just in case can you check you have a getter `getDetailIndex()` in your model (if `detailIndex` is `protected` or `private`)? Also, have you updated your database?

Comment: yes, getter is in model and works fine. DetailIndex is a private variable and getting access throught getter and setter

Comment: Do you have access to `positionId` as well?

Comment: Have you tried `detail_index`?

Comment: Do you have access to positionId as well? I dont know, i want to know how this works

Comment: detail_index also does not exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should check if your detailIndex key exists before accessing it.

<kbd>Solution 1</kbd> Create the `detailIndex` key if it does not exists to avoid terners

```
{% for row in issue.data %}

  {% if row.detailIndex is not defined %}
    {% set row.detailIndex = '' %}
  {% endif %}

... your business here

{% endfor %}
```

<kbd>Solution 2</kbd> Use a terner to get your `detailIndex` value. This works but isn't nice to read :)

```
{{ row.detailIndex is defined ? row.detailIndex : '' }}
```

<kbd>Solution 3</kbd> Use the `default` filter to avoid undefined attributes exceptions

```
{{ row.detailIndex | default('') }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your data is in the array is possible that one member has a key `detailIndex`, and the other is not.
Try to

```
{{ row.detailIndex is defined ? row.detailIndex : '' }}
```

**Update 1**

Another try

```
{{ if 'detailIndex' in row|keys ? row['detailIndex'] : '' }}
```

Comment: Another error: "Item "detailIndex" for "Array" does not exist in ..."

Comment: Please try second solution

Comment: `in` will look inside array values, not array keys. Your first solution should work anyway